# Replicating Express.js Middleware Pattern for User Roles in Next.js 13 API Routes

Tags: express, authentication, next.js, middleware, next.js13

In Express.js, I have a pattern where I assign user roles to the req object in middleware, which are crucial for access control within the route handlers. This data isn't sensitive per se but shouldn't be modifiable by the client:

```js
// Express.js example
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // Assume authentication middleware has validated the user and assigned roles
  req.userRoles = getUserRoles(req.user);
  next();
});

app.get('/some-protected-route', (req, res) => {
  if (req.userRoles.includes('admin')) {
    // Perform admin-specific actions
  }
  // ... Other role-based logic
  res.send('Access granted based on user roles');
});
```

I’m currently adapting to Next.js 13 and looking for a similar server-side pattern where I can add such user role information to the request, and ensure it’s not client-modifiable. [I saw a way which uses HTTP headers on the NextJS13 Middleware()](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/edge-functions-modify-request-header) for passing such information, but I have concerns about the client being able to manipulate this. I'm thinking I can just start by deleting the Header in the middleware in an attempt to prevent the user from setting it but there are still some http attack vectors.

How can I implement a secure and proper pattern in Next.js 13 for setting and using user roles within my API routes that aligns with the framework's best practices?

Thank you!